# Manipulate struct field when using interface

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface

The title might be misleading, but to the point...

I have a single interface `Expression`:

```
type Expression interface {
    String() // skiped in implementation below
}
```

The interface is implemented by multiple structs, some of which implements same interface as a field value:

```
type IdentExpression struct {
    value string
}

type UnaryExpression struct {
    token string
    value Expression
}

func (a *UnaryExpression) Simplify() {
    var finalValue Expression
    switch a.value.(type) {
    case UnaryExpression:
        tmp := a.value.(UnaryExpression)
        switch tmp.value.(type) {
        case UnaryExpression:
            tmp = tmp.value.(UnaryExpression)
            finalValue = tmp.value
        }
    }

    a.value = finalValue
}
```

Given expression `-(-(-(1)))`, `UnaryExpression.Simplify()` will simplify the expression to `-(1)`. ([play](https://play.golang.org/p/_rX36Y2J2E))

I would like to extend the interface with `Simplify()` method:

```
type Expression interface {
    Simplify()
    String() string
}

// ...

func (a IdentExpression) Simplify() {} // do nothing
```

Resulting code does not work ([play](https://play.golang.org/p/nhrxj9W5kU)):

> main.go:29: impossible type switch case: a.value (type Expression) cannot have dynamic type UnaryExpression (missing Simplify method)
>
> main.go:30: impossible type assertion:
>
> ```
> UnaryExpression does not implement Expression (Simplify method has pointer receiver)
> ```
>
> main.go:59: cannot use UnaryExpression literal (type UnaryExpression) as type Expression in field value:
>
> ```
> UnaryExpression does not implement Expression (Simplify method has pointer receiver)
> ```
>
> main.go:60: cannot use UnaryExpression literal (type UnaryExpression) as type Expression in field value:
>
> ```
> UnaryExpression does not implement Expression (Simplify method has pointer receiver)
> ```

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068779/how-to-modify-fields-in-struct-using-methods-from-interface), which looks similar however I do not know how to apply it in my case.

Comment: remove the pointer reference in Simplify function. Your code should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that you are using a pointer receiver in your definition of `Simplify()` with respect to `UnaryExpression`:

```
func (a *UnaryExpression) Simplify()
```

The other methods you are implementing don't use a pointer receiver:

```
// One example
func (a IdentExpression) Simplify() {}
```

Typically, in Go, it is considered best practice to have all methods on the same type use the same type of receiver (i.e. if one method uses a pointer receiver, they all should. Likewise, if one method uses a non-pointer receiver, they all should for that particular type).

In this case, the code will compile if you remove the pointer receiver from the `Simplify` method of `UnaryExpression`. Hope this helps!

Edit: [Here is a more comprehensive answer that explains exactly why this error happens, it's really a good read.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824044/2909262)

Comment: If I remove the pointer, the code compiles, but not works :) Still, your answer together with the answer you linked help me to find the issue - I needed to replace all my assertions to pointers ([here's the fixed code](https://play.golang.org/p/b8zSPGy1lt))